# Do you have any static code analysis tool for ruby which can used as plugin in eclipse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse

I am looking for eclipse plugin which will provide following thinks for ruby language

1. check-style Error(template for ruby)
2. bugs (like find-bugs)
3. code coverage(like Emma)
4. duplicate code

i have installed Apatana plugin in eclipse so that i can use eclipse as ruby editor.Is there any plugin for static code Analysis for ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/) is your one stop shop for Eclipse Plug-ins. There is a Ruby one listed: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/liclipse but I don't know if it fits your needs.